# Where to transform data, NSViewController or NSArrayController?

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, nsarraycontroller, nsviewcontroller

**I'm confused about *where* the transformation of data from Core Data to an `NSView` subclass takes place.**

After reading Apple's [Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/HowDoBindingsWork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002373-174515) they seem to suggest making that transformation happen in `NSArrayController`.

[image]

But, then I read their [Bindings Message Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/MessageFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002149-186092-BABBIHFF) section, and it implies in step 10 that transformations take place in an `NSViewController` subclass.

[image]

I've also heard that `NSArrayController`, or anything from `NSController` shouldn't be subclassed. But, then I read from [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22876609/5569902) that `NSController` and its subclasses are meant to be subclassed whenever you have a different form of data going out than coming in to an `NSView`.

*So, which is it?*

#### My Application

I've designed a candlestick graph that takes a number of objects from a custom class `Candle` to represent the `CAShapeLayer` and other properties.

To me, this is a perfect place for `NSArrayController` to manage all the `Candle` objects I have for any particular candlestick graph `NSView`.

Some of my data, I need to transform from price `Float` values to pixel `CGFloat` values. There's some geometry and math that I'm doing to get that.

Obviously, `NSArrayController` will handle the `Candle` objects, but *does the data transformation happen in `NSViewController` or `NSArrayController`?*

Comment: "view-controller binding" is the binding from the view to the controller, not a `NSViewController` (didn't exist in 2003). A binding can have a value transformer (subclass of `NSValueTransformer`) which does the transforming.

Comment: @Willeke Oh! So, that means "step 10" is not actually in `NSView` but in an `NSController` subclass that has an instance of `NSValueTransformer` for the binding transformation, right? So, I would subclass `ValueTransformer` (I guess the API was updated). That means `NSArrayController` still shouldn't be subclassed, right?

Comment: The binding has an optional value transformer (you can set it in the XIB/Storyboard or in code) and this value transformer transforms the value. `NSValueTransformer` is `ValueTransformer` in Swift. `NSArrayController` shouldn't be subclassed in this case.

Comment: @Willeke That makes more sense. Last question, were would you instantiate `NSArrayController`? Some say it should be in the `NSViewController` subclass, but the `NSView` subclass is the one that needs it for the `bind` method. I've also thought about putting with in an NSWindowController subclass since the view can reference its window. Then, how would a Core Data `bind` reference the `NSController` instance?

Comment: Usually the view controller owns the array controller.